# How to load managers for differents users from a csv file on Office 365 through Powershell and also to know who is one's manager?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm new to powershell and more to it, I'm even newer to exchange online read server so please bear with me.

I'm trying to update through powershell, the line managers,  which are in a csv format , of all the employees working in our company.

I know how to do it manually (see the 4 steps below)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I'm clueless on how to do it by bulkload.

It seems that the cmdlet `set-user` with the option `manager` can do that.

If it is the case, I will find something.

But what bugs me is that there is no way to find the manager of a user with `Get-User`.

Any helps/tips/links are appreciated as the documentation is quite poor.

Cheers

PS: if my explanation was still unclear, please read this http://blog.goptg.com/blog/2011/09/06/set-up-manager-in-exchange-and-sharepoint-online-in-office-365

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the Manager property isn't actually an Exchange property : it's an Active Directory property (in the case of o365 it's in AzureAD which might get synched from a local AD). In short : set this property on your local AD using Set-ADUser (if you are using dirsync), OR use Set-AzureADUserManager (if you're not using dirsync OR when AD writeback is configured in the sync).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found the answer to my question [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/How-to-load-managers-for-differents-users-from-a-csv-file-on/m-p/151129/highlight/true#M8456)

```
Import-CSV blabla.csv | % { Set-User $_.UserPrincipalName -Manager $_.Manager }
```